# Make the tire spin in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I already model a car for my racing game.I want to make the tire spin without seperating the tire from the car.[image: gtr and camaro]

im using blender 2.79b

Comment: so it is all one object? That would be *possible* but completely not worth it. Just make each tire a separate object then parent them to the car. Now you can just rotate the tires.

Comment: i have try it.but when i play the game the tire is missing

Comment: @mrcar put your mix file to review it, if you can but your question does not give much of where to suggest a solution since it is not known if it is a single mesh or if no different bad or how are you using the bones in your model